# A question about homotopy: Let L be an m-dimensional linear subspace of $R^n$, how to show that $R^n$\ $L$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-m-1}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I met about the following question:

Let L be an m-dimensional linear subspace of $R^n$, how to show that $R^n$\ $L$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-m-1}$?

It seems to me, that perhaps, I can do something like induction, since the case that $m = 0$ is trivial, is that a valid approach? Since I am stuck on the further steps on construction...

Comment: You can avoid induction by noticing $\mathbf{R}^{n} \setminus L$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbf{R}^{n-m} \setminus\{0\}) \times \mathbf{R}^{m}$.

Comment: That sounds nice, so is it obvious for using such a homeomorphic? I mean currently, I do have finished the case that L is a point, aka m = 0, but I am also confused with your approach. Would you mind offering more detailed explaination? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\mathbb{R}^n=Vect(e_1,...,e_n)$ where $L=Vect(e_1,...,e_m)$. Consider the map $f_t:\mathbb{R}^n-L\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n-L$ defined by $f_t(x_1,...,x_n)=(tx_1,...,tx_m,x_{m+1},..,x_n)$ where $t\in [0,1]$. It defines a deformation retract between $\mathbb{R}^n-L$ and $V=Vect(e_{m+1},...e_n)-Vect(e_{m+1},..e_n)\cap L$ and $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}-\{0\}$.