# Homotopy equivalence of $\mathbb{R}^n / \{L, W\}$ where $L, W$ are two linear subspaces of fixed dimension $k$ which intersect trivially

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was reading this question [A question about homotopy: Let L be an m-dimensional linear subspace of $R^n$, how to show that $R^n$\ $L$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n-m-1}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101148/a-question-about-homotopy-let-l-be-an-m-dimensional-linear-subspace-of-rn-h). I understood that $\mathbb{R}^n / L$, where $L$ is a $k$ dimensional linear subspace, is homotopy equivalent to $S^{n - k - 1}$.  I tried to generilize this, but i failed even in simplest case: Suppose that $L, W$ are two linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\dim W = \dim L = k$ and $W \cap L = \{0\}$. Which good space is homotopy equivalent $\mathbb{R}^n / \{W, L\}$?

Comment: Do you mean $W\cup L$ by $\{W, L\}$?